# Second call to DSS WSO2 service endpoint in service chaining fails server 500 error

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service that implements the service chaining pattern described quite adequately elsewhere on the internet.

Quite simply, I have one sequence calling a DSS web service operation that then passes control to another receiving sequence that calls another DSS web service operation on the same endpoint. This second call fails with a server 500 error and this faultstring

```
<faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://localhost:9765/services/TMC_CRIME_SERVICE.SOAP11Endpoint and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring>
```

Where this endpoint is exactly the same as the one called in the first sequence. How can this be? I have tried replacing the second call to a mockservice in SoapUI which works fine so doesn't appear to be a problem with my proxy service but something to do with the second call to the DSS server. 
There is a line in the debug output that states "ConnectionPool A connection to host : localhost on port : 9765 is available in the pool, and will be reused", I don't know if this has anything to do with it but including it anyway. The logs (with debug turned on) don't point to anything else obvious.
I am really stuck on this with no logical solution - please any advice???
Thanks
Conrad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set "SOAPAction" header in your receiving sequence..

Comment: Excellent - thanks very much. So simple when you know. Curious as to why this doesn't need explicitly setting for the first call to the same endpoint.

Comment: Could not tell exactly, without checking your full synapse configuration. But, requests are dispatched to a particular service/operation based on some information. If you check axis2.xml, you can find number of dispatchers which does that task.(eg: requestURI based dispatcher, soapaction based dispatcher) If system, could not use any of this above  suitable dispatching mechanism to find correct operation, the above error will be thrown..